# Is there a way to create transparent windows with Tkinter?

Tags: python, user-interface, window, tkinter, transparent

I'm trying, ultimately, to create "oddly-shaped windows" with Python using the Tkinter module. But for now I will settle for being able to make the background transparent while keeping child widgets fully-visible.

I'm aware this is done with wxPython and some other modules, but I'm inquiring as to the limits of Tkinter.

Can Tkinter create a clear Canvas or Frame? Can it pack UI elements without a canvas or frame? Can individual UI elements be transparent?

Can it pass mouse-click locations back to the system for processing any windows below it in the Z stack?

Answer (score 33):

The option `root.attributes('-alpha', 0.1)` can be used to make a transparent window

```
from Tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.attributes('-alpha', 0.3)
root.mainloop()
```

However in this case even the widgets on the root will inherit the transparency.

**Update for Linux (Tested on Ubuntu)**

The above code does not work on Linux machines. Here's an update that works on Linux.

```
from tkinter import Tk # or(from Tkinter import Tk) on Python 2.x
root = Tk()
root.wait_visibility(root)
root.wm_attributes('-alpha',0.3)
root.mainloop()
```

Not sure if this works on Windows.

Comment: Interesting. Though your example works, it seems to be incompatible with `root.overrideredirect(True)`; if I add that before the `wait_visibility` call, it causes the window blink (it appears fully opaque, and immediately gets transparent).

Comment: The 'window blink' phenomena happens for me irrespective of `overrideredirect` call. I guess it is the result of `wait_visibility` which waits till the window becomes fully visible to next allow for adding the `alpha` attribute thus causing the blink.

Comment: @tao this is great. Is there any way to make the window frame opaque but the window contents transparent?

Comment: @crypdick   AFAIK, this is not possible in Tkinter.  wm_attributes('-alpha',0.3) is only available on the top level window, so transparency can only be added on the top level.

Comment: The proposed solution : root.wm_attributes('-alpha',0.3) raises error on my Linux distibution (WindRiver):

root.wm_attributes("-alpha", 0.2) 
File "/opt/python27-x86_64/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1553, in wm_attributes return self.tk.call(args) _tkinter.TclError: wrong # args: should be "wm attributes window"

Any suggestion, pls?

Comment: @user929298 this seems unusual. Can you post a minimal but full working code of an example that would throw this error. Also it would be good to know the Tkinter version

Comment: Thank you from coming back! I will create a new question is will post a link here -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48843580/python-2-7-tkinker-linux-windriver-how-to-make-trasparent-window

Comment: First method works on Windows 7 with Python 3.7.2. Do you know if there some way to do this with an individual `Frame`?

Comment: @martineau: Tkinter does not allow transparency on individual widgets like the `Frame`

Comment: @bhaskarc Is there a way for just the root to be transparent and not the items within it?

Comment: @CoolCloud Did you able to do that? transparent background?

Comment: @MericOzcan Nope, there is no individual control over transparency.

Comment: @CoolCloud what you suggest than? buy a macbook?

Comment: @MericOzcan I dont think it is OS problem, I think tkinter does not support it, though you have `root.attributes('-transparentcolor','#f0f0f0')`, just thought about this now, so not sure if its perfect, but yes.

Comment: Ubuntu does not have transparentcolor attribute. @CoolCloud

Comment: @mericozcan Maybe. Not sure.

Answer (score 7):

## Summary as of late 2019:

As of TCL/TK version 8.6, the `alpha`, `fullscreen` and `topmost` window attributes work on ALL platforms (Windows, Mac and Linux):

https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/wm.htm#M9

Previous versions of the manual noted that there **PREVIOUSLY WERE** platform differences (only some platforms supported those 3 attributes). But as long as you use the latest TCL/TK, you're guaranteed that all of those attributes will work on ALL platforms!

There are still platform quirks on LINUX, since each window attribute feature relies on the operating system's underlying window manager (on Mac and Windows they're always capable, but on Linux there are tons of different window managers/compositors, and NOT all support transparent windows, etc). It says that in case transparency is not supported, the `alpha` property will stay at `1.0` if you try to read it again later. However the page also notes that on Linux (X11), the attributes are updated asynchronously which means that you can't trust the value you read (if you change alpha and then immediately try to read it, you'll still read the old value, so you can't use that method to check if alpha was successfully changed on Linux).

As for the other answers saying that you first need to use `root.wait_visibility(root)` on Linux to make sure the window is visible on screen before setting the `alpha` attribute... I don't know, since I don't have a Linux machine to check. But I heavily doubt that it's needed anymore, since the official manual says that alpha is supported and says nothing about that command being necessary. Either way, it doesn't hurt to add the `wait_visibility` trick too... It is simply a command that runs a very brief event loop that waits until the actual window has appeared on the user's screen. So it's probably still a good idea to add that command before all of your attribute-setting. Especially since it's *proven* to help the alpha work on Linux on *old* TCL/TK versions! *PS: You don't need the `(root)` argument, and should type `root.wait_visibility()` instead, which means "wait for `self` (root in this case since we called the command on the root object)".*

### Update:

Daniel in the comments below has let me know that `root.wait_visibility()` is still necessary on Ubuntu 19.10. Although he didn't specify his Python, TCL/TK or TkInter versions so maybe they're outdated on his system. Either way, sounds like it's a safer bet to always include that command for backwards compatibility!

Comment: I can confirm on Ubuntu 19:10 (default window mananger) you still need the `root.wait_visibility()` for it to work but as you say you don't need the root argument.

Comment: @DanielWorthington-Bodart Thanks for checking and letting everyone know! Answer updated. If you see this, it would be helpful to know your Python version, TCL/TK version, and TkInter (python module) version.

Comment: Check these answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12605003/non-standard-windows-with-tkinter

Comment: @Izalion Hmm, that link has nothing at all to do with alpha transparency (which this question was about). But still, that's a nice link for those who want to make borderless windows. Although the people at your link say that borderless windows only work on Mac and Windows. Anyway, thanks for sharing some additional, useful knowledge :-)