# Tkinter, transparent background, Linux

Tags: python, linux, tkinter

Is there a way to get a transparent background in a Tkinter window on Linux?

The only way I see currently is:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

root.overrideredirect(True)
root.wait_visibility(True)
root.wm_attributes("-alpha", 0.0)

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=300, height=300)
canvas.pack()
canvas.create_rectangle(50, 25, 150, 75, fill="red")

root.mainloop()
```

However, this is not what I want. I want to get the background to be transparent so my overlay can be something else.

I found a couple posts here, but they only cover bg transparency on Windows and Mac OS. The Linux related one is only alpha?

[linux mint tkinter transparent window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19080499/transparent-background-in-a-tkinter-window)

[transparent background in a tkinter window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19080499/transparent-background-in-a-tkinter-window)

Answer (score 5):

It worked for me on Ubuntu 20.04, Linux Mint 20.1, Cinnamon
Python 3.6

```py
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
#root.overrideredirect(True)
root.wait_visibility(root)
root.wm_attributes("-alpha", 0.5)
root.mainloop()
```

Use `root.overrideredirect(True)´ if you want that the window manager does not handle the window at all, except when you explicitly tell it to map or unmap it.

Comment: `root.overrideredirect(True)´ is not essential and has the confusing and unrelated effect that the window can not be closed by normal means. It is somewhat related to having a transparent window, so I leave it in, but comment it out.

Answer (score 4):

I'm pretty sure this is going to work.

```
root.wm_attributes("-alpha", 0.5)
root.wait_visibility(root)
```

Comment: Hi  @SuspectAverage5. Thanks for your answer. Usually answers with an explanation are more welcomed here. Would you like to update your answer to provide short explanation?

Answer (score 2):

Add this line:

```
root.wait_visibility(root)
```

before the "root.wm_attributes.." line as mentioned in [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18394597/is-there-a-way-to-create-transparent-windows-with-tkinter) 
It works for me on Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid "Tkinter window on Linux" does not make sense.
Linux is a "command line" OS, so no windows with linux !

To have windows on Linux, you must use a "desktop environment" (KDE, Gnome, Xfce, LXDE...)

So the question should be "Is there a way to get a transparent background in a Tkinter window on <**XXX**>?"
*XXX = the desktop environment you use*

For Gnome, the best answer I found is at [How to make Gtk+ window background transparent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3908565/how-to-make-gtk-window-background-transparent)
(see "code in python + GTK3").

Comment: The desktop environment is not relevant here. All use an X11 window system. Not even the window manager is relevant, as one of the answers demonstrates, currently.