# TKinter, place widgets on certain parts of the window aligning with the background image

Tags: python, tkinter

I would like to have my buttons and text neatly placed within the confines of the "Login" box area.  The "Login" box is actually part of the background PNG image that I load with TKinter.  I would like to get my widgets placed nicely within that Login box in the background.  I am currently using grid(), but for some reason they are not aligning with that Login box.  How can I adjust my code to get things inside of the Login box?

```
def build_login_screen(root):
    background_image = PhotoImage(file="./loginScreen.png", name="background_image")
    background_label = Label(root, image=background_image, name="background_label")
    background_label.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)
    background_label.image = background_image
    login_button = Button(root, text="Login", name="login_button", command=lambda: login(root))
    login_button.grid(row=5, column=1)
    quit_button = Button(root, text="Quit", name="quit_button", command=root.destroy)
    quit_button.grid(row=8, column=1)
    server_select = Combobox(root, name='server_select')
    server_select['values'] = (remote_server, local_server)
    server_select.current(0)  
    server_select.grid(row=4, column=1)
    server_select.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", clickServer)
    label_server_status = Label(root, padx=50, text="Checking server status..", name="label_server_status")
    label_server_status.grid(row=4, column=2)
    label_server_status_value = Label(root, padx=50, text=server_availability, name="label_server_status_value")
    label_server_status_value.grid(row=4, column=3)
```

[image: tkinter window]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion is to create a frame with a transparent background.  You the place this frame (using the place layout manager) so that it is positioned exactly over the rectangle in the center.  Then you can add the buttons to the transparent frame using standard layout managers.  This arrangement would be more flexible and easier to understand.

Widgets with transparent backgrounds are supported in TkInter versions >8.6, which is probably what you have unless your Python installation is very old.  For more information see: [Is there a way to create transparent windows with Tkinter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18394597/is-there-a-way-to-create-transparent-windows-with-tkinter)

Answer (score 2):

As your interface includes an image with a fixed size, the easiest solution would be to define the position of your Buttons with the `place` geometry manager (instead of the `grid` manager), as you already did to locate your image. Simply find coordinates by trial-and-error, until you get something visually pleasing.

You may still use `grid` for the other widgets...

Answer (score 1):

You can neatly place all your widgets using the `grid` geometry manager. Also you must consider providing some *padding* using the following options `padx, pady, ipadx & ipady` to make your GUI look neat and aligned.

I have commented some lines of your code as they were probably defined in some other section of the code which you didn't include in your question.

So basically the changes I made were that I used only the `grid` system. Set the label `background_label` inside your `root` window, and then arranged all the other widgets inside of the `background_label` so that there is a hierarchy

`root` (contains) `background_label` (contains) `Buttons, labels and other widgets`

And finally gave some padding to each of the widgets.

**Code:**

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

root = tk.Tk()

background_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file="./img/bg.jpg", name="background_image")
background_label = tk.Label(root, image=background_image, name="background_label", height=200, width=160)
background_label.grid(row=0, column=0, pady=10, padx=10, ipady=10, ipadx=3)
background_label.image = background_image

login_button = tk.Button(background_label, text="Login", name="login_button", command=lambda: login(root))
login_button.grid(row=1, columnspan=3, pady=(4,8))

quit_button = tk.Button(background_label, text="Quit", name="quit_button", command=root.destroy)
quit_button.grid(row=2, columnspan=3)

server_select = ttk.Combobox(background_label, name='server_select')
#server_select['values'] = (remote_server, local_server)
#server_select.current(0)  
server_select.grid(row=0, column=0, pady=4, padx=(6,5))
#server_select.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", clickServer)

label_server_status = tk.Label(background_label, padx=50, text="Checking server status..", name="label_server_status")
label_server_status.grid(row=0, column=1, pady=4, padx=(0,5))

label_server_status_value = tk.Label(background_label, padx=50, text='server_availability', name="label_server_status_value")
label_server_status_value.grid(row=0, column=2, pady=4, padx=(0,5))

root.mainloop()
```

**Output:**
This is what the GUI looks when you run the above code

[image: background image with widgets]

You can play around with the padding options and set them to your requirements. Hope you understood my explanation.