# Python tkinter How to make a label transparent?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have to make window blur. When the user clicks a button, `popup_window` shows up and background of window changes with blur.

```
root = tk.Tk()
## when button shows up, 
root.attributes('-alpha', 0.3)
```

This works on Windows perfectly. However, I have to do it same on linux, debian.
I know, on Tkinter 8.6, that should work on linux. But. in my case, debian linux, it's not.

So, I tried in many ways.

1. Make the label with window geometry size (whole size) and overlap the `root_window` and change the color or label with transparent color, and put the blurred dark image on label. However, I don't know how to set "transparent color" on the label.
2. I tried to make canvas to do it. But similar issues about transparent color still happened.

Can I make the label transparent? or make the window blur on linux? in another way? not attributes('-alpha')

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to create transparent windows with Tkinter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18394597/is-there-a-way-to-create-transparent-windows-with-tkinter)

Comment: check this, https://stackoverflow.com/a/18430628/10849457

Comment: sorry to say that... it doesn't work... root.wm_attributes('-alpha', 0.3) doesn't work. in any case... even if I add root.wait_visibility()... Thx, anyway