# Python: Is there a way to change the tkinter window shape?

Tags: python, tkinter

I've created a bordeless window using tkinter and I was wondering if there was a way to change the shape into a rounded rectangle? As well as make buttons rounded too?
Here is my current code:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk


root = tk.Tk()
root.overrideredirect(1)
window_width = root.winfo_reqwidth()
window_height = root.winfo_reqheight()
print("Width", window_width, "Height", window_height)
# Change the position of the window on screen
position_right = int(root.winfo_screenwidth() / 2 - window_width / 2)
position_down = int(root.winfo_screenheight() / 2 - window_height / 2)
root.geometry("+{}+{}".format(position_right, position_down))
# Change how it looks look into changing the shape and any animations we could add
frame = Frame(root, width=500, height=150,
                           borderwidth=2, relief=RAISED, bg="#0D0E50")
frame.pack_propagate(False)
frame.pack()
b_minimize = Button(frame, text="<", height=10, bg="light blue", fg="white", borderwidth=1, command=root.quit())
b_minimize.place(x=0, y=0)


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44099594/how-to-make-a-tkinter-canvas-rectangle-with-rounded-corners

Comment: No, it's not possible to change the window shape. However in Windows you can set a specific color to be transparent, so if you make the edges that color it will look like it's a different shape. To make rounded Buttons you would have to make the Button widgets yourself from images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi i think this could help you:

[Different shapes of windows in tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64294866/different-shapes-of-windows-in-tkinter)

[Non-standard windows with Tkinter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12605003/non-standard-windows-with-tkinter)

An easy way to change button style is the usage of pictures!

Comment: You´re welcome @HaloDonutsJ, kindly press the upvote if I was able to help you.

Comment: I dont have 15 reputation i could if i did