# Non rectangular shape or transparent background tkinter or any other library python?

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter, background

Here is my problem. I developed a tkinter GUI for my project. However I am stuck with tkinter limitations. I developed python gui to create a virtual view for a red table as below. The window does not have any border or title. It is just put on the a picture background which is outside of the code.

[image]

However as you can see it is not lively enough for me. I want it to look like this:

[image]

Is there a way to do this in tkinter? I tried transparent backgrounds, however in Ubuntu transparent background with visible object is not possible. Also You cannot make different window shapes other than rectangle. What is your suggestions? Should I use another library. I really need an expert opinion about this.

[Transparent background reference](http://%20https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19080499/transparent-background-in-a-tkinter-window)

[Different window shape other than rectangle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64294866/different-shapes-of-windows-in-tkinter)

My environment : Ubuntu 16.04 Python 3.5.2

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make a tkinter window rounded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68845235/how-to-make-a-tkinter-window-rounded)

Comment: @TheLizzard the question is for Windows, You can solve it on windows OS, however the problem is on Ubuntu OS. Library differs depending on the OS.

Comment: I know that `tkinter` tries to be consistent on all OSes that it supports. I have Ubuntu on my computer and I will check it out in a few hours.

Comment: @TheLizzard Like I said same code on windows run differently with Ubuntu. If I remember correctly that was the problem. But I solved it  by using a different Library. WxPython was more difficult to use but, it has capabilities like custom window shapes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So to solve my issue I found a python library wxPython:

You can check this link it creates [Wx non rectangular shape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4873063/what-is-the-simplest-way-to-create-a-shaped-window-in-wxpython)

It creates the the window using inheritence. I tried selected answer and It solved my question.

Btw I tried QTPython, Kivy, tkinter. Non of them had straight example such wxPython.

Answer (score 0):

You can't specifically change the shape of a Tkinter Window, but you can create a [canvas](http://tkinter.fdex.eu/doc/caw.html) and design your own shape (then add your buttons and labels on this canvas if needed).

You can also take a look at PyQt or Kivy, but if you are confortable with Tkinter go with Canvas.

Comment: I  checked PyQt it does not support transparent background with non-trans objects. Kivy might to I am checking it. Also I know that I can create canvas, but I dont understand how it is going to help me. Canvas would be inside a rectangle non transparent window would be the same as my gui in first picture.

Comment: Please check these answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12605003/non-standard-windows-with-tkinter

Comment: I already check it. As far as I see wxPython can do this I will try it  and give answer.