# How to resize a tkinter overrideredirect window with a shape in it?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have made a tkinter window which is round in shape.
I am trying to resize the window.
Everything works fine, but when I try to move it, it becomes square again.

I have added the code to draw the shape again, but still it becomes squared.

Here's the code:

```
from tkinter import Label, Tk, Canvas, BOTH, PhotoImage, Toplevel
from tkinter.constants import BOTTOM, E, NW, RAISED
import pyautogui as pg

root = Tk()
root.overrideredirect(1)
root.attributes("-transparentcolor", 'white')
root.attributes("-topmost", 1)
root.geometry("500x500")

# Creating a canvas for placing the squircle shape.
canvas = Canvas(root, height=500, width=500, highlightthickness=0, bg='white')
canvas.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

def place_center(): # Placing the window in the center of the screen
    global x, y
    reso = pg.size()
    rx = reso[0]
    ry = reso[1]
    x = int((rx/2) - (500/2))
    y = int((ry/2) - (500/2))
    root.geometry(f"500x500+{x}+{y}")

def move(event):
        global rect
        fx = root.winfo_pointerx() - 250
        fy = root.winfo_pointery() - 10
        root.geometry(f"500x500+{fx}+{fy}")
        # if fx > 1 and fy > 1:
        #         canvas.delete(rect)
        #         rect = round_rectangle(0, 0, fx, fy, radius=50, fill="#1fa5fe")


def round_rectangle(x1, y1, x2, y2, radius=25, **kwargs): # Creating a rounded rectangle
        
        points = [x1+radius, y1,
                x1+radius, y1,
                x2-radius, y1,
                x2-radius, y1,
                x2, y1,
                x2, y1+radius,
                x2, y1+radius,
                x2, y2-radius,
                x2, y2-radius,
                x2, y2,
                x2-radius, y2,
                x2-radius, y2,
                x1+radius, y2,
                x1+radius, y2,
                x1, y2,
                x1, y2-radius,
                x1, y2-radius,
                x1, y1+radius,
                x1, y1+radius,
                x1, y1]

        return canvas.create_polygon(points, **kwargs, smooth=True)
def cl(event):
        root.quit()
        
def resize(event):
        def end(event):
                global rect
                root.bind("<B1-Motion>", move)
        global rect
        global x, y
        root.unbind("<B1-Motion>")
        x = root.winfo_pointerx() - root.winfo_rootx()
        y = root.winfo_pointery() - root.winfo_rooty()
        if x > 0:
                fx = root.winfo_rootx()
                fy = root.winfo_rooty() + y
                ht = root.winfo_height() - y
                if ht > 0:
                        root.geometry(f"{x}x{ht}+{fx}+{fy}")
                        canvas.delete(rect)
                        rect = round_rectangle(0, 0, x, ht, radius=50, fill="#1fa5fe")
        root.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", end)

place_center()

# Creating the squircle
rect = round_rectangle(0, 0, 500, 500, radius=50, fill="#1fa5fe")

root.bind("<B1-Motion>", move)
root.bind("<Button-3>", cl)

rx = root.winfo_rootx()
ry = root.winfo_rooty()
side = Label(canvas, text='  \n', background="blue")
side.place(x=500-10, y=500-10)
side.bind("<B1-Motion>", resize)
root.unbind("<B1-Motion>")

root.mainloop()
```

Here're some images.

Before resizing:
[image: Before resizing]

After resizing and moving:
[image: After resizing]

If you need, I am using Windows 10.

PS: Sorry if the code isn't written in good manner! I am creating this as a sample, which I will apply in my other apps when done.

Thank you.

Comment: Instead of `pg.size()`, you can use `<any tkinter widget>.winfo_screenwidth()` and `<any tkinter widget>.winfo_screenheight()`

Comment: @TheLizzard Thanks, but it does the same (I don't think changing the medium will affect much)

Comment: It just removes your `pyautogui` dependency. It's better to use a `tkinter` function when you can if you are using `tkinter` for the project.

Comment: Hi!

I solved the issue. When I move the window, it goes back to the default geometry. That's why it looks square.

I changed the code and now it's working good!
I will post an answer so that other people can get help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NVM, I solved the problem.

When I was moving the window, it was set to default geometry, which made it look round.

I have changed it and here's the updated code for the `move()` function:

```
def move(event):
        global rect
        fx = root.winfo_pointerx() - 250
        fy = root.winfo_pointery() - 10
        try:
                root.geometry(f"{x}x{ht}+{fx}+{fy}")
        except Exception:
                root.geometry(f"500x500+{fx}+{fy}")
```

The final code (with a few changes):

```
from tkinter import Label, Tk, Canvas, BOTH, PhotoImage, Toplevel
from tkinter.constants import BOTTOM, E, NW, RAISED, TOP

root = Tk()
root.overrideredirect(1)
root.attributes("-transparentcolor", 'white')
root.attributes("-topmost", 1)
root.geometry("500x500")

# Creating a canvas for placing the squircle shape.
canvas = Canvas(root, height=500, width=500, highlightthickness=0, bg='white')
canvas.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

def place_center(): # Placing the window in the center of the screen
    global x, y
    rx = root.winfo_screenwidth()
    ry = root.winfo_screenheight()
    x = int((rx/2) - (500/2))
    y = int((ry/2) - (500/2))
    root.geometry(f"500x500+{x}+{y}")

def move(event):
        global rect
        fx = root.winfo_pointerx() - 250
        fy = root.winfo_pointery() - 10
        try:
                root.geometry(f"{x}x{ht}+{fx}+{fy}")
        except Exception:
                root.geometry(f"500x500+{fx}+{fy}")
        # if fx > 1 and fy > 1:
        #         canvas.delete(rect)
        #         rect = round_rectangle(0, 0, fx, fy, radius=50, fill="#1fa5fe")


def round_rectangle(x1, y1, x2, y2, radius=25, **kwargs): # Creating a rounded rectangle
        
        points = [x1+radius, y1,
                x1+radius, y1,
                x2-radius, y1,
                x2-radius, y1,
                x2, y1,
                x2, y1+radius,
                x2, y1+radius,
                x2, y2-radius,
                x2, y2-radius,
                x2, y2,
                x2-radius, y2,
                x2-radius, y2,
                x1+radius, y2,
                x1+radius, y2,
                x1, y2,
                x1, y2-radius,
                x1, y2-radius,
                x1, y1+radius,
                x1, y1+radius,
                x1, y1]

        return canvas.create_polygon(points, **kwargs, smooth=True)
def cl(event):
        root.quit()
        
def resize(event):
        global rect
        global x, y, ht
        x = root.winfo_pointerx() - root.winfo_rootx()
        y = root.winfo_pointery() - root.winfo_rooty()
        if x > 0:
                fx = root.winfo_rootx()
                fy = root.winfo_rooty() + y
                ht = root.winfo_height() - y
                if ht > 0:
                        root.geometry(f"{x}x{ht}+{fx}+{fy}")
                        canvas.delete(rect)
                        rect = round_rectangle(0, 0, x, ht, radius=50, fill="#1fa5fe")

place_center()

top = Canvas(canvas, height=50, bg="#1fa5fe", highlightthickness=0)
top.pack(side=TOP, pady=2)

# Creating the squircle
rect = round_rectangle(0, 0, 500, 500, radius=50, fill="#1fa5fe")

top.bind("<B1-Motion>", move)
root.bind("<Button-3>", cl)

rx = root.winfo_rootx()
ry = root.winfo_rooty()
side = Label(canvas, text='  \n', background="blue")
side.place(x=500-10, y=500-10)
side.bind("<B1-Motion>", resize)
root.unbind("<B1-Motion>")

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: What if they resize and move around? Does it still work?

Comment: @Matiiss Yes it works. That's what the problem was and it's solved now.